# Is it possible to have more than one bean id (JavaMailSenderImpl) to enable having multiple email senders?

Tags: java, xml, spring, dependency-injection, jakarta-mail

I have a mail sender set up in config file: spring/servlet-context.xml
which has username and password set.
I've come up with a specific use-case where I need to send mail ***from*** a different email account.
Is it possible to set this up in this same config file.

At first, I thought this would mean simply to add another bean id having the other email account's username and password set within, but then that didn't make sense to me how is the JavaMailSender going to tell which sender I want each time?!

My code:
In servlet-context.xml:

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
    <property name="port" value="587" />
    <property name="username" value="default_email@gmail.com" />
    <property name="password" value="***1***" />
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.debug">false</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.sendpartial">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

[ I thought to add here:

```
<bean id="anotherMailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    ...
    <property name="username" value="another_email@gmail.com" />
    <property name="password" value="***2***" />
    ...
</bean>
```

]

And a Java Class responsible for email sending:

```
public class MailService {
    private static JavaMailSender mailSender;

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public void setMailSender(JavaMailSender mailSender) {
        this.mailSender = mailSender;
    }

    public void sendMail(final String aSubject, final String aContent, final String toMail, final List<String> attachedFileUrls, String aFilename) {
        MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        try {
            MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true,"UTF-8");
            helper.setFrom(simpleMailMessage.getFrom());
            helper.setTo(toMail);
            helper.setSubject("A subject");
            helper.setText("some content", true);
        } catch (Exception e) {...}
        Thread thread = new SendMail1(message);
        thread.start();
}

    class SendMail1 extends Thread {
        MimeMessage message;

        SendMail1(MimeMessage message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

        public void run() {
            mailSender.send(message);
        }
    }
}
```

(It doesn't help changing setFrom and setTo functions, because they only set the *visual* "to" and "from" in recipent's mail box)

At the moment mailSender "knows" somehow  by the config settings above to send email to the email set in servlet-context.xml .

I would like to add sendMailFromSpecialSender function which will send email from other sender.

Is this possible?
If it is, then how?

**UPDATE:**
After posting this question I found a partial answer to my question by Bill Shannon:

> The simple solution is to use a separate Session for each sender and send each message one at a time.

So...
1. How do I create a separate Session for my other sender case?
2. Does the configuration in servlet-context.xml enable having a separate session with other configuration, or can I leave that as it is?

Thank-you

Comment: I don't know how you are using these beans but you have to add the other bean to your Java class. Just like what you did with `mailSender`, this time do it with `anotherMailSender` Then you are able to use it inside your function.

Comment: to @AmirM : 1.  I presume that when I define JavaMailSender foo, it automatically creates mailSender object with attributes defined in xml config file. Therefore, I could not do what I understand from your suggestion.   2. See UPDATE of my question, to understand the direction I'm in for seeking the answer. 3. Thank-you

Comment: 1. no, it's not like that, if you have different beans of a type, you can instantiate them. There are ways, for that. You just need to somehow instantiate it. maybe another setter like `setSimpleMailMessage`? maybe through constructor? autowiring? 2. I don't suggest that. I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seems to be about Spring's dependency injection, and how to inject two beans of the same class.

One good way to do this is to [use a `@Qualifier`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers):

```
public void setPrimaryMailSender(@Qualifier("primary") JavaMailSender mailSender) {
    this.mailSender = mailSender;
}

public void setSecondaryMailSender(@Qualifier("secondary") JavaMailSender mailSender) {
    this.secondaryMailSender = mailSender;
}
```

and then in your bean definitions:

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <qualifier value="primary"/>
    ...
</bean>

<bean id="anotherMailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <qualifier value="secondary"/>
    ...
</bean>
```

In this way, you can easily inject two fields of the same type.

Comment: Excellent! I'll give it a try. Thank-you, meanwhile

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use another mailSender in your sendMail() method.
In that method you can have conditional check something like

```
if(condtion){
  MimeMessage=mailSender.createMimeMessage();
 else {
    MimeMessage=otherSender.createMimeMessage()
 }
```

Similar check in your inner class can help ypu to decide which sender to use.

Comment: The main problem is - I don't know how to create this otherSender. I know it may be confusing that mailSender in config file and mailSender in Java code have the same name, but what connection do they have one to another?